# How should I check if a flag is set in a flags enum?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Of the two methods below, which do you prefer to read?
Is there another (better?) way to check if a flag is set?

```
 bool CheckFlag(FooFlag fooFlag)
 {
      return fooFlag == (this.Foo & fooFlag);
 }
```

And

```
 bool CheckFlag(FooFlag fooFlag)
 {
      return (this.Foo & fooFlag) != 0;
 }
```

---

Please vote up the method you prefer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two expressions do different things (if fooFlag has more than one bit set), so which one is better really depends on the behavior you want:

```
fooFlag == (this.Foo & fooFlag) // result is true iff all bits in fooFlag are set


(this.Foo & fooFlag) != 0       // result is true if any bits in fooFlag are set
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was only looking at it one way. ie, "Is my bit set"  I guess it could be helpful to know if "Any" bit is set as well!

Answer (score 6):

```
bool CheckFlag(FooFlag fooFlag)
{
    return fooFlag == (this.Foo & fooFlag);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i prefer the first one because it's more readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool CheckFlag(FooFlag fooFlag)
{
    return (this.Foo & fooFlag) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first one.  I use !=0 sparingly in boolean expressions.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a positive thinker:

```
bool CheckFlag(FooFlag fooFlag)
{
  return this.Foo & fooFlag == 1;
}
```

Comment: What if FooFlag's value is 2?

Comment: He said he is a positive thinker :)

Comment: I stand corrected - thinking before writing is helpful ;)